# Не срабатывает обработчик removeEventListener

Tags: javascript

Создать кнопку, по нажатию на которую, создаётся сообщение. При повторном нажатии сообщение исчезает.

```
<body>
    <button id="btn">Click!</button>
    <script>
        'use strict'
        let parent = document.body;
        let el = document.createElement('div');
        let listener = function(e) {
            el.innerHTML = "I was born!";
        }
        btn.addEventListener('click', listener, true);
        btn.removeEventListener('click', listener);
        parent.appendChild(el);
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: вы добавляете и сразу удаляет обработчик, чего вы ожидаете?

Comment: Ожидаю, что он после второго клика будет удалять. А как надо?

Comment: _после второго клика будет удалять_ вы удаляете обработчик, как это может быть связано с текстом?? почитайте что делает `removeEventListener`

Comment: вам нужно в самом обработчике удалять текст, а не удалять сам обработчик

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
'use strict'
const parent = document.body;
const el = document.createElement('div');
let second_click =false;
let listener = function(e) {
  if (second_click) {
    second_click = false;
    el.innerHTML = "";
  } else {
    second_click = true;
    el.innerHTML = "I was born!";
  }
}
btn.addEventListener('click', listener, true);
parent.appendChild(el);
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click!</button>
```

Comment: сообщение должно удаляться, а не обработчик __При повторном нажатии сообщение исчезает__

Comment: @ThisMan подправил)

Comment: Скрипт, работает правильно, но не понятно. Если второй клик false, то inner - пустота, а если true, то 'i was born!" По логике вроде наоборот должно быть, т.е. со второго клика - пустота. По моему понял, происходит как бы переключение, при повторном клике?

Comment: @Trulimon при первом клике мы добавляем текст, при повторном удаляем. Можно поменять местами)